# Remove object of JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do I remove the object of JSON? I am using Jackson API 2.6.3

Example of my JSON String

```
{  
   "movieList":[  
      {  
         "movieID":1,
         "title":"TITLE 1",
         "type":"DIGITAL",
         "status":"COMING SOON",
         "synopsis":null,
         "director":null,
         "mRating":"G",
         "casts":null,
         "showTimes":[  
            {  
               "date":"01/12/15",
               "time":"22:00"
            },
            {  
               "date":"01/12/15",
               "time":"23:30"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to be able to remove the whole showTimes object given its index.

Something like `showtimesList.get(index).remove()` And if it is the last object in the arrayList, the value should be set to `null`.

As suggested by one of the answer, I am converting the JAVA Object `ShowTime` to JSONNode by so

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode showTimesNode = objectMapper.convertValue(movieList.get(index).getShowTimes(), JsonNode.class);
Iterator<JsonNode> itr = showTimesNode.iterator();
int counter = 1;
while(itr.hasNext() && counter<=showTimeChoice){
    if(counter==showTimeChoice){
        itr.remove();
        Cineplex.updateDatabase(cineplexList);
        System.out.println("Sucessfully removed!");
        break;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

But it's throwing the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)` when I tries to remove the 2nd element of `showTimes`  on the above given JSON String

Which is

```
{  
  "date":"01/12/15",
  "time":"23:30"
}
```

Comment: @Gimby: No, the linked question is JavaScript, this is Java with Jackson.

Comment: Can you not use [ArrayNode](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/hatchery/jackson/0.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/impl/ArrayNode.html)? Not a Jackson User, just saw it in the API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917141/remove-an-empty-element-from-json-file-with-jackson/30917454#30917454

Answer (score 4):

```
for (JsonNode personNode : rootNode) {
    if (personNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
       if (personNode.has("showTimes")) {
          ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) personNode;  
          object.remove("showTimes");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to use personNode.isObject() instead of instanceof.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (I'm not a Jackson user, so YMMV):

```
((ObjectNode) movieListElement).remove("showTimes");
```

EDIT:

```
JsonNode movieListElement = ((ArrayNode) root.path("movieList").get(index);
```

Comment: At first glance this seems to delete the whole `showTimes` field.

Comment: Yes. "I would like to be able to remove the whole showTimes object" is what you said. Getting to the proper `movieList` element given the index, I leave to you.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part on `given its index`. I can get the movieList element fine. But how to I specific which index of the showTimes that I want to delete? I do not want to delete the whole array of showTimes. Only the selected index.

Comment: `movieListElement` is not `"movieList"` node, but an element of the array that is `movieList`. You get it from the `"movieList"` `ArrayNode` by [`get(index)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html#get\(int\)).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
public void removeShowTime(int pos){
    final JsonNode movieList = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json).get("movieList").get(0);
    final JsonNode showList = movieList.get("showtimesList");
    Iterator<JsonNode> itr = showList.iterator();
    int counter = 0
    while(itr.hasNext() && counter<=pos){
       if(counter==pos){
           itr.remove();
       }
       counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `JSONArray` is not Jackson.

Comment: @Amadan ohh ok missed the jackson part correcting the answer

Comment: @Sudheer If I can get the `showTimes` field as a object of List<ShowTime> how can I convert it to a JsonNode?